# Report List Help

Tags: 2003

I am new to administrating SharePoint and have run into something I do not understand.  In my SharePoint site on the left side of the page I have a section/box that says "View All Site Content".  Under that is Report and a list of two reports.  Next is Lists and one list.  Next id Documents and a bullet point of Shared Doucments and finally I have Recycle Bin.

I need to add more reports but do not know how to add to the list.  The Reports header is not a link (I can not click on it).  While the Lists and Doucments headers to are links that can be clicked on to maintain the items below them.

Does anyone know how to maintain\add reports to this section?

Thanks!

Dale

Answer (score 1):

Dale,

I don't have experience with 2003 as it is a pretty dated platform.  However, I will talk you through what to check and it might make sense.  Every Site has a site actions menu.  Navigate to Site Actions.  You should see something related to Quick Launch or Navigation.  Start there and see if the action is there for you to work with.  You should be able to add links and headers accordingly using this control.

Answer (score 0):

Open you ReportList

Go to Settings Menu

click Title, Description and navigation

Display this document library on the Quick Launch?  Click yes to show it on left navigation.